# Event.DISPLAYING AS3 Not compile?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

`Event.DISPLAYING`

Why this event wont work when i try to compile the flashe (CTRL+ENTER)

Flash gives me error

> 1119: Access of possibly undefined property DISPLAYING through a reference with static type Class.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such constant.

If you want to use a custom event you will have to either subclass `Event` (don't forget to implement the clone-method) or you can use a constant of your own like this:

Define the constant in your class :

```
public static const DISPLAYING:String = "myevent_displaying";
```

Then use it when dispatching:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event(MyClass.DISPLAYING));
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you have a user defined class named `Event` imported in to the code. If that is the case, use the fully qualified class name `flash.events.Event.DISPLAYING` to force the correct class.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/events/Event.html#DISPLAYING

So what about this then?

I need to know if my SWF is currently activated in the TAB. Couse some enterframe evnts are  not working anymore when i open a new tab in my browser.